# React - Redux-Toolkit items in cart

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning react with redux-toolkit. I am stuck with some actions there.

I want to add quantity in Cart, so if I add same item more than once it should be like X1/x2/x3...etc.
And I want to delete items/item but only with the same ID ( when I click delete only delete that one ex. APPLE)

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: 0,
  itemsInCart: [],
  quantity: 0,
  totalCount: 0,
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    removeItem: (state, action) => {},
    removeAll: (state) => {
      state.cartItems = 0;
      state.itemsInCart = [];
      state.totalCount = 0;
    },
    addToCart(state, action) {
      state.itemsInCar = state.itemsInCart.push(action.payload);
      state.cartItems += 1;
      state.totalCount += action.payload.price;
    },
    showCart: (state) => {
      state.hidden = !state.hidden;
    },
  },
});
export const { showCart, addToCart, removeAll, removeItem } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: what are you passing on addToCard and give an example output of state.itemsInCar

Comment: In addToCart I am passing {item} (ex. {id:0,name:'',image:''.....})

Answer (score 1):

```
addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemInCart = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      if (itemInCart) {
        itemInCart.quantity++;
      } else {
        state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
      }
    },
```

Comment: in the above code you first capture a single item then check if it already exists in cart. If it exists then increase the quantity else push a new item in the cart